# get the value of multiple wysihtml5 editors in jquery in yii

Tags: html, regex, yii

i just use wysihtml5 editor in yii view page.

in this view page two editor are created.

here is the code.
 this is first one ediotr

```
echo $form->html5EditorRow($PrintTemplateModel, 'details', array('rows' => 5, 'height' => '130px','label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Header Layout',
    'options' => array( //you could set to false any button that is not desired
            'font-styles' => true,
            'font'=>true,
            'emphasis' => true,
            'lists' => true,
            'link' => true,
            'image' => false,
            'html' => false,
            'color' => false,
            'htmltable' => true,
            'textjustifyCenter'=>true
    )));
```

and this is second one

```
echo $form->html5EditorRow($PrintTemplateModel, 'footer', array('rows' => 5, 'height' => '130px','label'=>false,'placeholder'=>'Footer Layout',
    'options' => array( //you could set to false any button that is not desired
            'font-styles' => true,
            'font'=>true,
            'emphasis' => true,
            'lists' => true,
            'link' => true,
            'image' => false,
            'html' => false,
            'color' => false,
            'htmltable' => true,
            'textjustifyCenter'=>true
    )));
```

when i try to get value of both editors in jquery, it give me only value of second one editor.

jquery code

```
var val = editor.getValue();
        console.log(val);
```

html code generated is like this

```
<ul class="wysihtml5-toolbar" style=""><li class="dropdown"><a class="btn dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#"><i class="icon-font"></i>&nbsp;<span class="current-font">Normal text</span>&nbsp;<b class="caret"></b></a><ul class="dropdown-menu"><li><a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="div" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">Normal text</a></li><li><a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="h1" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">Heading 1</a></li><li><a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="h2" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">Heading 2</a></li><li><a data-wysihtml5-command="formatBlock" data-wysihtml5-command-value="h3" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">Heading 3</a></li></ul></li><li><div class="btn-group"><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="bold" title="CTRL+B" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">Bold</a><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="italic" title="CTRL+I" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">Italic</a><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="underline" title="CTRL+U" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on">Underline</a></div></li><li><div class="btn-group"><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="insertUnorderedList" title="Unordered list" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on"><i class="icon-list"></i></a><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="insertOrderedList" title="Ordered list" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on"><i class="icon-th-list"></i></a><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="Outdent" title="Outdent" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on"><i class="icon-indent-right"></i></a><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="Indent" title="Indent" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on"><i class="icon-indent-left"></i></a></div></li><li><div class="bootstrap-wysihtml5-insert-link-modal modal hide fade"><div class="modal-header"><a class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</a><h3>Insert link</h3></div><div class="modal-body"><input value="http://" class="bootstrap-wysihtml5-insert-link-url input-xlarge"></div><div class="modal-footer"><a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a><a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Insert link</a></div></div><a class="btn" data-wysihtml5-command="createLink" title="Insert link" href="javascript:;" unselectable="on"><i class="icon-share"></i></a></li></ul>

<textarea rows="5" id="PrintTemplate_details" style="width: 100%; height: 130px; display: none;" name="PrintTemplate[details]" placeholder="Header Layout"></textarea>

<input type="hidden" name="_wysihtml5_mode" value="1">

<iframe class="wysihtml5-sandbox" security="restricted" allowtransparency="true" frameborder="0" width="0" height="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255); border-collapse: separate; border: 1px solid rgb(204, 204, 204); clear: none; display: inline-block; float: none; margin: 0px 0px 10px; outline: rgb(85, 85, 85) none 0px; outline-offset: 0px; padding: 4px 6px; position: static; top: auto; left: auto; right: auto; bottom: auto; z-index: auto; vertical-align: middle; text-align: start; box-sizing: content-box; -webkit-box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset; box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.0745098) 0px 1px 1px 0px inset; border-top-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-right-radius: 4px; border-bottom-left-radius: 4px; border-top-left-radius: 4px; width: 100%; height: 130px;"></iframe>

<span class="help-block error" id="PrintTemplate_details_em_" style="display: none"></span>
```

any solution for this.
i want value of both editors in jquery only.

thaks in advance.

Comment: Have u tried `$(editor).each(function(){ ... });`

Comment: Or you can name the editors separately and refer to them individually.

Comment: $(editor).each(function(){ ... }); not working, and we can get value by name. because its only have one method editor.getValue()

Comment: Can you show me the html created by the editor and the wrapper divs. I will be able to get to all the editors.

Comment: i have post html code generated by editor

Comment: It seems like you have one instance of wysihtml5 editor. Anyway try this `$(document).ready(function(){
    $('textarea').each(function(index){
        console.log($(this).html());
    });
});` and check the console to see if you get html from all the wysihtm5 instances.

Comment: its given me blank val.

Comment: sorry not `$(this).html()` it should be `$(this).val()`. Anyway you can try the answer below.

Comment: yes i got it $(this).context.value it works. thans bro... thank u very much

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

Change your first editor to:

```
echo $form->html5EditorRow($PrintTemplateModel, 'details', 
                            array(
                                  'rows' => 5, 
                                  'height' => '130px',
                                  'label'=>false,
                                  'placeholder'=>'Header Layout',
                                  'id'=>'MyEditor1',   //<=== Add this line (for the second editor use 'id' =>'MyEditor2'
                                  'options' => array( .....)
                                ));
```

Now you will be able to refrence them in jQuery as:

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var editor1 = $('#MyEditor1').val();
    var editor2 = $('#MyEditor2').val();
});
```